# android update project --path . --target android-25 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, android, environment-variables, android-sdk, linphone

While executing command in terminal

```
update project --path . --target android-25
```

I am getting error

```
Invalid or unsupported command "update project --path . --target android-25
Supported commands are:
android list target
android list avd
android list device
android create avd
android move avd
android delete avd
android list sdk
android update sdk
```

I have already set down environment variables using

```
export JAVA_HOME=<path_to_jdk>
export ANDROID_HOME=<path_to_sdk>
export PATH=$PATH:<path_to_tools>:<path_to_platform_tools>:<path_to_ndk>
```

One Strange thing was when I had set down this variables via command, the change doesn't reflected in `/etc/environment` when opened using `gedit /etc/environment`

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was getting error `unsupported command "update project"` because I was using **sdk** with **tools** version **26.0.1**. As this command is **deprecated** now so it is already **removed** from tools version **25.3.0**

I found this in documentation

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools.html

So, if still want to fire this command then you have you downgrade your sdk tools to version **25.2.5** or less.

For that rename your sdk/tools folder to tool1 or else to keep it as a backup and download required sdk tools and paste that [tools] folder inside sdk folder. I have followed this link to download sdk tools or platform-tools :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11514698/6795090

In the same way you can also upgrade your tools or platform-tools. But if you are using **android-studio** then I recommend to update them from SDK Manager.

One last thing, to update project using "update project" command you need to set environment variables like this:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=<PATH_TO_SDK>
export PATH=$PATH:<PATH_TO_PLATFORM_TOOLS>:<PATH_TO_TOOLS>
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: Can verify that after hours of looking Google has gave no work around other then using a pre v25.3 version. Other option is rebuild it all using Gradle like they want people now to do

Comment: Linux version: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-linux.zip